# Deleted ssh keys from security page Digital Oceans, but still i am allowed to ssh

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I have created a ssh key for my droplet at digital oceans. After few days I have deleted the key from [security page](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/security) and still I am able to ssh using putty with that key. Is it necessary to delete the key from authorized_keys file. If so, then what is the use of adding/deleting ssh keys to droplet on their above mentioned security page?

Question at digital ocean -  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-remove-ssh-keys-for-the-droplet

Comment: I am just a beginner. I thought it's a general thing, maybe I am missing out some where, that's why I asked it here.

Answer (score 0):

As the [digital tutorial page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets) says 
"You can create new DigitalOcean droplets with an SSH key already set up on them by adding your computer’s SSH key to the control panel.".

To setup a ssh key for the droplet it is needed to add your newly created key to the droplet's control panel.

You are able to access the droplet even after you deleted the ssh from security page because now the ssh also resides inside your droplet's ~/.ssh/ folder(remote machine).

[To authenticate using SSH keys, a user must have an SSH key pair on their local computer. On the remote server, the public key must be copied to a file within the user's home directory at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. This file contains a list of public keys, one-per-line, that are authorized to log into this account.
When a client connects to the host, wishing to use SSH key authentication, it will inform the server of this intent and will tell the server which public key to use. The server then check its authorized_keys file for the public key, generate a random string and encrypts it using the public key.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys)
So, it necessary to delete the key from authorized_keys file to stop ssh access to the remote machine.

After the droplet creation security page lists the keys just to show what all ssh keys you used for all your droplets.Deleting them from security page will not prohibit you from accessing your droplet.